# How to implement search functionalities?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, apache-kafka

Currently we are making a memory cache mechanism implementation in search functionalities.
Now the data is getting very large and we are not able to handle it in memory.   Also we are getting more input source from different systems (oracle, flat file, and git).

Can you please share me how can we achieve this process?

1. We thought ES will help on this. But how can we provide input if any changes happen in end source? (batch processing will NOT help)
2. Hadoop - Not that level of data we are NOT handling 
   Also share your thoughts.

Comment: What kind of search are you talking about?

Comment: given text sting sting..

Comment: For text search, read up on full text search engines.  Start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full-text_search.  And check out the 30+ products that that page links to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we are getting more input source from different systems (oracle, flat file, and git)

I assume that's why you tagged Kafka? It'll work, but you bring up a valid point

> But how can we provide input if any changes happen...?

For plain text, or Git events, you'll obviously  need to alter some parser engine and restart the job to get extra data in the message schema.

For Oracle, the GoldenGate product will publish table column changes, and Kafka Connect can recognize those events and update the payload accordingly.

If all you care about is searching things, plenty of tools exist, but you mention Elasticsearch, so using Filebeat works for plaintext, and Logstash can work with various other types of input sources. If you have Kafka, then feed events to Kafka, let Logstash or Kafka Connect update ES

Comment: Actually , given search string (from my app), will lookup into GIT , oracle and flat file. Earlier we pull the records (sync) and did some search. But now records are growing anything. we couldn't manage current implementation. i had discusstion with my friends and they shared some tools , ES and kafka and redis. Not sure which i have to choose .. share your thoughts @cricket_007

Comment: Mix all the tools... ES is the only one you just listed that actually searches things. Kafka sends data from point X to point Y. Redis doesn't really fit into that picture

Comment: ES - for searching and Kafka for pull the datasources .. believe kafka also will help any update in end sources, will get update in search also .  please confirm my understanding

Comment: Yes, Kafka Connect can read data sources and sink to other systems through a Kafka message bus

Comment: Thanks a lot @cricket_007